# Stackoverflow deploying webapp generated with spring-boot to jboss

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jboss, spring-boot, stack-overflow

I'm building a webapp with Spring-boot and running and testing it perfectly alright. I've also configured it to create a WAR file by following the instructions on [their official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html).

When I run `mvn clean package` it builds successfully and generates the war file. When I deploy the war file to jboss 6 however, I get this error:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/energyworx-conversion-tool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.StackOverflowError

        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.deployArchive(DeploymentUtils.java:146) [jopr-jboss-as-5-plugin-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.deploy.AbstractDeployer.deploy(AbstractDeployer.java:119) [jopr-jboss-as-5-plugin-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.helper.CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.createContentBasedResource(CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.java:124) [jopr-jboss-as-5-plugin-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.helper.CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.createResource(CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.java:56) [jopr-jboss-as-5-plugin-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.ApplicationServerComponent.createResource(ApplicationServerComponent.java:304) [jopr-jboss-as-5-plugin-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_71]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_71]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_71]
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ComponentInvocationThread.call(ResourceContainer.java:525) [:3.0.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_71]
```

After setting logging to DEBUG, I also see this before the error above:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Error visiting "/C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/energyworx-conversion-tool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/ciber/ewct/controller/IndexController.class"
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:268) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:409) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:397) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:102) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:181) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.DeploymentUnitScanner.scan(DeploymentUnitScanner.java:111) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.UrlScanner.scan(UrlScanner.java:96) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.deployers.ScanningDeployer.deploy(ScanningDeployer.java:95) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error visiting resource: VFSResourceContext @ com/ciber/ewct/controller/IndexController.class / BaseClassLoader@2d592fc0{vfs:///C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/energyworx-conversion-tool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war}, visitor: org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.GenericAnnotationVisitor@7e722452
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.IgnoreSetErrorHandler.handleError(IgnoreSetErrorHandler.java:56) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:91) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.AnnotationsScanningPlugin.visit(AnnotationsScanningPlugin.java:89) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.ScanningPluginWrapper.visit(ScanningPluginWrapper.java:112) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.FederatedResourceVisitor.visit(FederatedResourceVisitor.java:101) [jboss-classloading.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

What am I doing wrong? I have no web.xml or Spring XML configuration files. I assume Spring-boot will take care of these for me. I'm building with maven and this is my POM.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>    
    <start-class>com.ciber.ewct.WebApp</start-class>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000</jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Mind providing your `IndexController` class?

Comment: It's just a class annotated with @Controller. I've checked the generated war and the .class file is there, under WEB-INF/classes/....

Comment: What annotations do you have in it?

Comment: @Controller and @ RequestMapping.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?